# How to remove column from spss output?

Tags: spss

I have a doubt in spss?

When I was run a output I need to remove the one column "BASE" Please help me how to remove from the output.

If it is not possible and also help me how to remove from the excel.

Comment: can't really help you without more details - how does your data look like? what analysis did you run? what exactly do you want to remove from the output?

Comment: can you please give me your contact whatsapp so only i cant share my file

Comment: you don't need to share your file - just edit your post and add a description of the data, a sample of the data if relevant. You can add a screenshot of your output and more explanations about the problem. You really need to show more effort in explaining the problem and what you tried so far, for others on the site to make the effort to help you...